# Issue with Process Delegate after implementing a non-persistent DAC

Tags: acumatica

I am struggling with getting my Process Delegate to wire up correctly after implementing the advice pointed out in this ticket [Implementing a DAC with no persisted fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962400/implementing-a-dac-with-no-persisted-fields). The processing page for the most part now behaves as we need. The records autoload based off of data pulled in via a ReST web service and we are not persisting any data to the ERP until the processing buttons are used. The issue I am having now is the SetProcessDeligate method is now not doing anything when I hit the process buttons. When I wire the older code into place that has one persistent field and requires a user to hit a load button the Process and Process All buttons work as expected. 
I have created this screencast to walk through and give visual context to the issue. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8vnp8p3556nj1e/issue%20with%20the%20PXProcessing%20page%20not%20wiring%20into%20the%20event%20handler%202019-01-03_12-57-50.mp4?dl=0
As always I am very grateful for any help. Thank you 
Robert

```
//This is how my Graph is defined now. 
public class CtpPaymentProcess : PXGraph<CtpPaymentProcess>
{
    //public PXAction<CtpPayment> checkForC2PPayments;

    public PXSetup<CtpSetup> setup;

    public PXProcessing<CtpPayment> Payments;

    public QueryPaymentsResponseViewModel paymentsFromCtpServer { get; internal set; }

    public IEnumerable payments()
    {
        paymentsFromCtpServer = CtpAcumatica.CheckForAllNewPayments(100);

        PXTrace.WriteInformation("Processing " + (paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments.Count) + " paymentsFromCtpServer");

        if (paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments != null)
        {
            // Loop processing each payment returned from the gateway, storing the 
            // information into non persisted cache.
            foreach (var payment in paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments)
            {
                if (!payment.IsMarkedRetrieved)
                {
                    yield return BuildCtpPayment(payment);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private CtpPayment BuildCtpPayment(PaymentViewModel payment)
    {
        var customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer,
                        Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>
                        .Select(this, payment.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

        //Todo: add assertion that will assert payment is made to only matching company payment.CompanyId
        //Todo: find out if we need to handel Bank Account Types differently payment.BankAccountType

        DateTime.TryParse(payment.Date, out var payDate);
        return new CtpPayment
        {
            CustomerID = int.Parse(payment.CustomerId),
            Customer = $"{customer.AcctCD}:{customer.AcctName}",
            Amount = payment.Amount,
            Description = $"Payment:{payment.Id}",
            Id = payment.Id,
            ApsTransactionID = payment.ApsTransactionId,
            Currency = payment.Currency,
            PaymentDate = payDate,
            Invoices = InvoicesAsString(payment)
        };
    }

    private static string InvoicesAsString(PaymentViewModel payment)
    {
        var Invoices = payment.Invoices.Select(x => x.InvoiceId);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string inv in Invoices)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} ", inv);
        }
        string result = stringBuilder.ToString();
        if (result.Length > 100) result = result.Substring(0, 96) + "...";
        return result;
    }

    private CtpAcumatica _ctpAcumatica;


    public CtpAcumatica CtpAcumatica
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ctpAcumatica == null)
            {
                var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PXGraph>();
                _ctpAcumatica = new CtpAcumatica(setup.Current.CtpUrl,
                    setup.Current.CtpApiKey,
                    "NoLongerNeeded", //todo: refactor this out.
                    "NoLongerNeeded", //todo: refactor this out.
                    graph);
            }
            return _ctpAcumatica;
        }
    }

    public CtpPaymentProcess()
    {
        Payments.SetProcessCaption("Process Payments");
        Payments.SetProcessAllCaption("Process All Payments");
        Payments.SetProcessDelegate<CtpPaymentProcess>(
            delegate (CtpPaymentProcess graph, CtpPayment payment)
            {
                graph.Clear();
                graph.ProcessPayment(payment, true);
            }
        );
        //Alternate attempt proved un-successful 
        //Payments.SetProcessDelegate(PaymentGenerationDelegate);

    }

    /* implemented as a test. will remove from production code
    private void PaymentGenerationDelegate(List<CtpPayment> list)
    {
        foreach (var payment in list)
        {
            ProcessPayment(payment, true);
        }
    }
    */

    private void ProcessPayment(CtpPayment payment, bool massProcess)
    {
        PXTrace.WriteInformation($"Processing {payment}");
        //for now we will only write to the trace window. 
        //Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        //stopWatch.Start();
        //createPayment(payment);
        //stopWatch.Stop();
        //PXTrace.WriteInformation($"Payment {payment.ApsTransactionID} finished in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} Seconds");
    }

    //todo: unfinished
    private void createPayment(CtpPayment paymentData)
    {
        var paymentFromCtp = CtpAcumatica.GetPaymentRecord(long.Parse(paymentData.Id));

        ARPaymentEntry arPaymentEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();

        ARPayment payment = new ARPayment
        {
            CustomerID = int.Parse(paymentFromCtp.CustomerId),
            CuryOrigDocAmt = paymentData.Amount
        };

        arPaymentEntry.CurrentDocument.Insert(payment);

        foreach (var invoice in paymentFromCtp.Invoices)
        {

            ARAdjust adj = new ARAdjust
            {
                AdjdRefNbr = invoice.InvoiceId,
                CuryAdjgAmt = invoice.Amount
            };
            arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Insert(adj);
        }
        arPaymentEntry.Persist();
        PXTrace.WriteInformation(arPaymentEntry.ToString());
    }
}

//This is the DAC definition.
[Serializable]
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(CtpPaymentProcess))]
//[PXNonInstantiatedExtension] this looked close
//to what we are looking for but experimenting 
//with it did not yield desired results.
public class CtpPayment : IBqlTable
{

    #region Selected
    public abstract class selected : IBqlField{ }
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public abstract class id : IBqlField { }
    //todo: find out what size we need 50 is just a guess.
    //[PXString(50, IsKey = true)] //We are able to get this to work only if 
                                    //we have at least one persisting field.
                                    //we can live with this but would prefer to 
                                    //have the whole class as non-persistent
    [PXString(50,IsKey = true)] //having only non persisting attributes will result in a 
                    //Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. error.
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Click To Pay Id")]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    public abstract class customer : IBqlField { }

    [PXString(100)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer")]
    public virtual string Customer { get; set; }

    public abstract  class description : IBqlField {}
    [PXString(200)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public abstract  class amount : IBqlField { }
    [PXDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Amount")]
    public  virtual decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    public abstract class customerId : IBqlField { }

    [PXInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer ID")]
    //todo: decorate this with the needed attributes to display friendly key instead of int.

    public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }

    public abstract class apsTransactionID : IBqlField { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Transaction ID")]
    public virtual string ApsTransactionID { get; set; }

    public abstract class currency : IBqlField { }
    [PXString(10)]//todo: determine best size. 10 is a guess.
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Currency")]
    public  virtual  string Currency { get; set; }

    public abstract class paymentDate : IBqlField { }
    [PXDate]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Date")]
    public virtual DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }

    public abstract class invoices : IBqlField { }

    [PXString(100)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Invoices")]
    public virtual string Invoices { get; set; }




}
```

Comment: The issue could be that you return new object every time from the delegate but processing page expect to re-use object in cache instead of being handed new data on each call. Same link as last time, try to implement the pattern which returns the object from Cached. Without object in cache data is strictly read-only.

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26563499/7376238

Comment: HB_Acumatica, I am very grateful for your help. I had implemented the first as the latter had commentary saying to use it if the user needs to do edits or inserts which is not required in this case. So it seems regardless of the record being read-only I still needed to implement the latter if I need to run a process over those read-only records. I have now changed my code to use the latter strategy and it appears to now be working.

Comment: Yeah I took a guess that the PXProcessing data view does indeed modify the records in cache and requires those modifications to stick in cache. With first method you are always picking from DB and whatever PXProcessing does to the record it gets overwritten when the data view delegate returns new object. By returning the objects already inserted in cache you keep the modifications that PXProcessing is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, HB_Acumatica for the direction on this.

Changing my code to use the following got to the end result I needed. I Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
    //old implementation that would not render any result when the process buttons where clicked.
    //public IEnumerable payments()
    //{
    //    paymentsFromCtpServer = CtpAcumatica.CheckForAllNewPayments(100);

    //    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Processing " + (paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments.Count) + " paymentsFromCtpServer");

    //    if (paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments != null)
    //    {
    //        // Loop processing each payment returned from the gateway, storing the 
    //        // information into non persisted cache.
    //        foreach (var payment in paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments)
    //        {
    //            if (!payment.IsMarkedRetrieved)
    //            {
    //                yield return BuildCtpPayment(payment);
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    public IEnumerable payments()
    {
        paymentsFromCtpServer = CtpAcumatica.CheckForAllNewPayments(100);

        PXCache cache = Caches[typeof(CtpPayment)];
        cache.AllowInsert = false;
        cache.AllowUpdate = false;

        if (cache.Current == null)
        {
            foreach (var payment in paymentsFromCtpServer.Payments)
            {
                if (!payment.IsMarkedRetrieved)
                {
                    cache.SetStatus(BuildCtpPayment(payment), PXEntryStatus.Held);
                }
            }
        }
        return Payments.Cache.Cached;
    }
```